# mod_rewrite .htaccess from subfoder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've this website structure

```
localhost/
    - administrator/
      - auth/
         - login.php
      - index.php

    - website/
      - index.php
```

In `index.php` I've a request to `localhost/auth/login`.
My needs is that: when a user makes a request to the path `localhost/auth/login` the request must be redirected to `/administrator/auth/login.php`.

I've tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /auth/login(.*) /administration/auth/login.php/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use anchors in your regex. Try this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/auth/login(.*)$ /administration/auth/login.php$1
```